# Ionic4 Unknown browser query

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-cli, ionic4, serve

I have practised Ionic a lot so these Problems are not new for me but I am unabale to solve this one.
I am currently trying to migrate my Ionic3 project to Ionic4.
To do this I have created a new Ionic4 tabs project.

Every time I try the Ionic serve command I am getting:
[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Unknown browser query

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's

Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.

[ng] See "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-9er5Id\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).


The Log file:
[error] BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
    at unknownQuery (D:\Wisex\Technik\Client\safehome_client\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:204:10)
    at D:\Wisex\Technik\Client\safehome_client\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:296:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (D:\Wisex\Technik\Client\safehome_client\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:237:18)
    at browserslist (D:\Wisex\Technik\Client\safehome_client\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:361:16)
    at new BuildBrowserFeatures (D:\Wisex\Technik\Client\safehome_client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\build-browser-features.js:17:35)
    at generateWebpackConfig (D:\Wisex\Technik\Client\safehome_client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:24:34)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Does anyone of you have an possible solution for this.
I am really greatful for help cause I takes my days to migrate by now.

Yours,
Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the last version of the angular cli?

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

It might also be useful to post the log

Comment: To be honest I am not sure. I will try that later on!

Comment: I installed Angular again now but I still have the same error code.
I have posted the content of the Log file in the description above!

Comment: I'm also having trouble. From what I have experienced with ionic, if Ionic/cordova and angular CLI is up to date issue might come from nodeJS version (I use nvm to switch from time to time), python and gradle version (I think it's more for the build) and your environment variables. Since you're starting from a blank project it would really be weird it comes from the project itself.

Comment: What could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent several hours to fix this .Hope it will help someone

Kindly follow the below steps:

1. find your npm path from the **environmental** variable. And copy that path and paste it  in notepad

[image]

2.Go to control panel ->**uninstall** the node js

3.after uninstalling,**restart** the system.

4.Now **go  to npm path** in file explorer.

5.And **delete** the  folder named **npm** and **npm-cache**

[image]

6.And now install the **node(LTS version**) and **angular**(refer from the below link for **step by step** installation)

https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/setup-angular-windows

**note**:Dont run the cmd as administrator.Unless ,the installation fails

7.Once you verified that angular is running fine using **ng serve -o**

8.Install the ionic by **npm install -g ionic@latest**

9.And run **ionic serve.**

10.Hope it helps.Happy coding :)