# Unhandled Exception Occurred: unknown browser query

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, npm

I am new to ionic and got the error mentioned in screenshot below. I have successfully installed following commands.

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

Used command:

```
basedir=$(dirname $(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`
```

Error:

[image]

New Error after deleting two files the "browserlist" (text file) from project directory, and also delete "browserlist.cmd" file.

[image]

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the answer here would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961636/ionic4-unknown-browser-query

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3938#issuecomment-272633128

Comment: after going through above links and found to delete the "browserlist" (text file) from project directory, and also delete "browserlist.cmd" file. That error has been resolved but getting different error. New error screenshoot has been updated.